# Understanding customElements processing order

Tags: javascript, custom-element

There is a point in time when a parent custom element can access its children before they are blessed with their custom methods.

```
class CustomParent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    // works
    this.children[0].textContent = "bar";

    // works
    setTimeout(() => this.children[0].test(), 0);

    // throws a Type error
    this.children[0].test();
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-parent", CustomParent);


class CustomChild extends HTMLElement {
  test() {
    this.textContent = "baz";
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-child", CustomChild);

document.body.innerHTML = `
<custom-parent>
  <custom-child>foo</custom-child>  
</custom-parent>
`;
```

How can this be possible and is it safe to defer `this.children[0].test()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the [*upgrading* process](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#upgrades) of Custom Element.

**1st step**: when you execute  `document.body.innerHTML = '<custom-parent><custom-child>foo</custom-child></custom-parent>'` the 2 elements are inserted in the page as **unknown elements**.

**2nd step**: the parent element is ***upgraded*** first. It can access its child (and then update its `textContent` property) as an ***unknown*** element. But it cannot access access the custom element `test()` method... because it is not a custom element yet!

**3rd step**: the child element is ***upgraded*** immediately after, and now gets a `test()` method.

**4th step**: the deferred `test()` call logically works :-)

See the example below. It uses `querySelectorAll( ':not(:defined)' )` to show that the child is upgraded after its parent.

```js
class CustomParent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super() ; console.log( 'parent upgraded') }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log( 'parent connected', this.children[0].outerHTML )
    // works
    this.children[0].textContent = 'bar'    
    // works
    setTimeout( () => this.children[0].test() )
    // throws a Type error
    try { 
       this.children[0].test() 
    } catch ( e ) { 
      //this shows the parent is upgraded, but not its child 
      var not_upgraded = document.querySelectorAll( ':not(:defined)' )
      console.log( 'not upgraded: ', ...not_upgraded )    
    }    
  }
}

customElements.define( 'custom-parent', CustomParent )

class CustomChild extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super() ; console.log( 'child upgraded') }      
  test() { this.textContent = 'baz' }
}

customElements.define( 'custom-child', CustomChild ) 

document.body.innerHTML = `
  <custom-parent>
    <custom-child>foo</custom-child>  
  </custom-parent>`
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I was confused about the `customElements.define` method. I imagined every `custom-child` element created after its call would be already "known", with all of their logic attached to them. I also realised `customElements.upgrade` is kind of equivalent to calling the constructor. If I write `customElements.upgrade(this)` before your try block, every child gets upgraded synchronously, and if I call it in a constructor I get a recursive function. Now I wonder if it's preferable to defer action like I did or to upgrade chidren before action (could there be side effects?).

Comment: Actually it's related to the way you created the elements (here with innerHTML). Alternatly, if you create the elements with new and then insert them the appendChild, you would already have the added methods at the time you insert it in the document. I don't think a method is better that another, as soon as you understand how it works.

Comment: @geoffrey thank you I didn't now the existence of the [upgrade()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/upgrade) method :-)